How to Populate an Attribute of Type String Array Using a Web Crawler Document Extractor?
How to Populate an Attribute of Type String Array Using a Web Crawler Document Extractor in Sitecore Search?
We have a hidden input field on product pages containing pipe-separated values. These values need to be mapped to a search attribute of type "Array of Strings".
<input type="hidden" name="Category" id="Category" value="Category A|Category B|Category C" />


// Sample extractor function. Change the function to suit your individual needs
function extract(request, response) {
$ = response.body;
var category=$('input[name="Category"]').attr('value').split("|");
return [{
    'brands':category,
    'description': $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content') || $('meta[property="og:description"]').attr('content') || $('p').text(),
    'name': $('meta[name="searchtitle"]').attr('content') || $('title').text(),
    'type': $('meta[property="og:type"]').attr('content') || 'arraywebsite_content',
    'url': $('meta[property="og:url"]').attr('content')
}];

}



